# Could Space Travel be achieved using a very strong magnetic field to warp space?

Tags: electromagnetism, space-travel, warp-drives

An [Alcubierre Warp Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) could theoretically achieve faster than light space travel but requires exotic matter or negative energy to compress space in front of the spaceship and expand space behind it. Could a similar effect be achieved by only compressing space in front of the spaceship?
As the spaceship fell into the gravity well and moved forward, space would automatically expand back to normal behind the ship as it rode the distortion wave. If this propulsion method worked, it would require only a fraction of the energy needed by the Alcubierre Warp Drive.
Also, if space could be compressed ahead of the spaceship using a very, strong magnetic field, no exotic matter or negative energy would be needed, just the electromagnetic force. Even if faster than light travel could not be achieved this way, a small constant acceleration, maintained over a long period of time would achieve a high near light velocity.

Comment: More Phys.SE questions about Alcubierre drive: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+alcubierre

Comment: Neat article: http://www.hawking.org.uk/space-and-time-warps.html and this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzMrNFd4oOk

Answer (score -2):

Yes if it was possible the focus the magnetic field like a laser and use another planets magnetic pole as a tether. The magnetic beam would have to be very fine not to collect metal space junk.

Comment: I don't see why a laser-like magnetic field would be able to make warp drives.